# Xcode 12 Beta: "No such module" for framework in same project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm working on a project that has four targets: an iOS and Mac framework, and an iOS and Mac example application target. The frameworks have identical code, and the example apps are very nearly using the same code (it's a SwiftUI app). I've done this sort of thing before, but now, while my Mac app and Mac framework happily co-exist and work fine, the iOS framework simply can't be found in the iOS example app.

[image: Error message showing my framework not being found]

Hoo boy, have I tried everything I can think of.

- Yes, the framework is present in the example app's "Frameworks, Libraries..." section under General, and also appears in the Build Phases "Dependencies" as well as "Link Binary with Libraries" sections.
- I've tried various values for the Framework Search Paths in Build Settings, though the Mac one has no value for that field and it's fine.
- Ditto for Runpath Search Paths. On the Mac it's "@executable_path/../Frameworks", and I've tried that and various others on the iOS side.
- The framework builds just fine by itself. I can look at it in Derived Data, and it seems to be there and present. Here's a capture of that folder.

[image: iOS Framework files in Derived Data]

I'm not sure what else to try at this point. I don't know if this is a bug in Xcode 12 Beta, perhaps? Or in Big Sur Beta? Is there anything else I can look at to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Not sure, but, can architecture be a problem here? How are you building the framework? I mean, for which platform?

Comment: The iOS framework is being built for arm using the standard architectures...

Comment: I created Test project, seems fine to me. Do you have same structure as I am using? https://github.com/k-thorat/SO-63385668

Comment: Yeah, this looks like my project setup. But there's no code in your app at all! LOL Agreed that yours compiles, so I guess we can rule out something fundamentally wrong with Xcode 12 Beta...

Comment: Here's a clue: I created a new iOS project, then in the original project with all the targets, I built the iOS framework. Then I dragged that framework into the new project, and it works! It seems that when the framework is built as a dependency, the build products are incomplete. Any idea why?

Comment: Tried on beta 6, still the issue persists. @AaronVegh - Did you find out any solution? Been breaking my head on this. TIA.

Comment: You can try the top answer of this ask. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978359/xcode-error-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-dylib-built-for-ios-f)