# No such module error in Xcode 12.4 Apple M1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In My Xcode 12.4 I can't build my projects anymore. Each time I do I get "No such module..." for each Pod. I haven't made any other changes to the project. I've cleaned, deleted Derived Data, restarted my computer, deleted and reinstalled the Pods, updated Cocoapods, added arm64 in excluded Architecture etc.

**I can run on my device but not on a simulator**

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Make sure you are opened the `yourproject.xcworkspace` instead of `yourproject.xcodeproj`

Comment: Yes, I opened  yourproject.xcworkspace

Comment: I can run  same opened project on my device but not on a simulator

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/14351818

Comment: @aheze as i mentioned in questions I use this setting but now I face this error :--

No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 arm64e i386 x86_64, EXCLUDED_ARCHS=(
    arm64
)).

Comment: @VijayParmar I ran into something like that before. I literally tried everything. After a couple hours when I came back to my computer, it worked. Maybe try that (taking a break and coming back)?

Comment: @aheze thanks for help, I face this issue in my every new project in latest Xcode in Apple m1, I don't recognise how to resolve this, in my other project I tried different ways to make project working, but this time I can't able to find proper solution

Comment: @VijayParmar yeah, M1 really is kind of weird when it comes to architectures...

Comment: You can try the first answer of this ask. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978359/xcode-error-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-dylib-built-for-ios-f)

Comment: You can try the top answer of this ask. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978359/xcode-error-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-dylib-built-for-ios-f)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Adding this to podfile helps me

```
post_install do |installer|   
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill! Your fix worked for me.
Do you understand why it works? If we are on an arm64 architecture, why should we exclude arm64 simulator architectures?

Answer (score 5):

For me the fix was Kirill's accepted answer, but I also needed to add  `arm64` for `Excluded Architectures` in target's `Build Settings`:

[image: 1]

Comment: Life saver. This needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac's with the new M1 chip:

1. Open Finder -> Applications
2. Right-click on XCode -> Select `Get Info`
3. Select the box for `Open with Rosetta`
4. Completely quit XCode and reopen.

Comment: This is a functional workaround but it means you'll be running in x86 compatibility mode, which means it'll be compiling slower etc