# No such module Alamofire, XCode 15.2 and M1 chip

Tags: ios, alamofire, apple-m1, xcode15

import Alamofire

Podfile
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.1.0'

computer:Ｍacbook Air with M1

After I type the command "pod install", the ios project builds and shows the error "No such module Alamofire". Before I upgraded XCode from 14.3.1, the problem existed. Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

pod install

The command type in the terminal, it appears the message as below:

Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `TzuchiMedicalApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Comment: Does the `pod install` command produce any errors or warnings?

Comment: Also, I assume that you're opening the workspace, not the project, right?
Finally, have you tried cleaning the build folder, deleting DerivedData, all usual stuff?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I got the answer from the article [No such module error in Xcode 12.4 Apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948010/no-such-module-error-in-xcode-12-4-apple-m1)

```
post_install do |installer|   
      installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      end
end
```

Comment: It's more that your dependencies are out of date or your project is misconfigured, or you have a CocoaPod which only works for the Intel architecture. This shouldn't be necessary in most cases.